# Clarification about Caylus favours

Tags: caylus

According to the rules book, the 3rd column of favours is available *after* the scoring of the dungeon. My question is, when scoring the dungeon, is it still considered as *before* the scoring? In other words I can't move my marker up to the 3rd row to collect 3 points or build a stone building, with the favours I've earned right after scoring the dungeon, correct?

Comment: you can play Caylus on-line with enforce rules, i think that this is the easiest way to know all the small details.  See https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=caylus

Answer (score 3):

Right: you can't move my marker up to the 3rd row to collect 3 points or build a stone building, with the favors I've earned right after scoring the dungeon. See the example on the last page of [the rules](http://www.ystari.com/caylus/CayUS.pdf):

> Orange has just gained a favor during the Dungeon scoring. He chooses the first line (prestige points), on which he already advanced in a previous phase. However,
> since the Dungeon is being scored, Orange can’t advance his marker. He leaves it on its space and gains 2 prestige points.